# Regex contain multiple string

Tags: c#, java, php, regex, expression

I have many problem for understand regex, i'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible.

I want a regex able to match with a string that contains "a" AND "b" in any order.

Example :

```
rrrarrbrr
```

match

```
rrrbrrarar
```

match

```
rrrbbbrrr
```

dosen't match

Is it possible to do that with the help of a regex? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While p.s.w.g's answer is certainly correct, it doesn't really generalize to more than two characters (you'd have to include every possible permutation of the order of characters). Usually, to make multiple assertions on an input, we use lookaheads:

```
^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)
```

`^` anchors the expression to the beginning of the string. This is more of an optimization and slightly helps the understanding (if the conditions cannot be matched at the beginning of the string, there is no need to check them again at later positions). The lookahead `(?=...)` then checks that there is an `a` somewhere down the string. But the lookahead does not actually advance the position in the string (it only **looks** ahead), so we're still at the beginning of the string, and can now check another condition (that there is a `b` somewhere down the string). This way you can easily add multiple conditions without regard to where in the string they are fulfilled.

Of course, as p.s.w.g. also said, for individual characters there is no need to use regex at all, but this technique can be useful if you want to check multiple more complex patterns in one go.

I highly recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to get you up to speedon regular expressions. They really look more daunting than they actually are. It also has a section (or rather two) specifically [on lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: +1 Nice trick, I'll have to remember this. Although it seems like it's only good for testing for a match. How could this be used to capture the `a...b` portion of the string? (Not part of OP's question, I'm just curious)

Comment: @p.s.w.g if your environment supports it, you can capture both `a` and `b` (and the captures' positions in the string) and extract the substring manually.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this pattern:

```
a.*b|b.*a
```

As in

```
bool containsAandB = Regex.IsMatch(input, "a.*b|b.*a");
```

Or simply:

```
bool containsAandB = input.Contains("a") && input.Contains("b");
```

If your dealing large inputs and you want to iterate over the string only once, a little bit of Linq can help:

```
bool containsAandB = input.Where(c => c == 'a' || c == 'b')
                          .Distinct().Take(2).Count() == 2;
```

Comment: Yes, no need to use a regex just because the problem involves a string.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Well, the regex-less version does iterate through the string twice instead of once. Not sure if the regex would be faster in this instance, though...

Comment: @Nolonar Linq can help in that case. See my updated answer, that *should* be the fastest solution.